# Python: Change the texture resolution limit individually ? Per Material?

Tags: python, texturing

in simplify (propreties) we have the option to reduce every textures size that are higher that 2k, for example, to this same resolution. **Is it possible to simplify individually an image texture? or every image texture from a material? via python of course.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you mean independently from the simplify ? just by changing image size ? If you are looking in to this I have a small experience since I did something similar before few years in order to bake textures and export them for webgl (DAE) with the minimum res I could afford for online apps.

there is a scale property in bpy.data.image object, according to this thread it must be relatively easy to implement it, although from a quick search I found out that this is only for new made images created in blender.

Thus for you will need an external module to accomplish it, so take a closer look on the second response which is mentioned also as the solution.

[How to change image dimensions of a generated image from Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42685/how-to-change-image-dimensions-of-a-generated-image-from-python)